# what's the fastest method to export a table through sql query ? 11g - performance

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g, query-performance

I'm connected to the oracle server remotely. I need to export a table data(the whole table) with millions of records but due the hosting restrictions I can only use SQL (no exp , expdp) . Therefore I'm wondering what's the sql query that with the best performance. My table structure is as following :

```
  CREATE TABLE "AUTO"."AUTO" 
   (    
    "AUTOJ" NUMBER(16,0), 
    "AUTOK" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "AUTOL" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "AUTOM" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "AUTON" NUMBER(4,0), 
"AUTOZ" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "AUTOAA" NUMBER(32,0), 
    "AUTOBB" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "AUTOBC" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "AUTOBD" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "AUTOBW" DATE, 

    "V" NUMBER(32,0), 
    "AUTOT" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "AUTOU" NUMBER(10,0), 
"MK" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AUTOA" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AUTOB" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AUTOC" VARCHAR2(68), 
    "AUTOD" VARCHAR2(64), 
    "AUTOE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AUTOF" DATE, 
    "AUTOG" NUMBER(16,0), 
    "AUTOH" VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AUTOI" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "AUTOW" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "AUTOX" NUMBER(15,2), 
    "AUTOY" NUMBER(15,2), 

    "AUTOMK" DATE, 
    "AUTOPO" VARCHAR2(128), 
    "AUTOCV" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "AUTOON" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "AUTOXA" NUMBER(1,0),
"AUTOBY" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "AUTOCC" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "AUTODA" DATE, 
    "AUTOO" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "AUTOP" VARCHAR2(1), 
    "AUTOR" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "AUTOS" NUMBER(3,0),  
    "AUTOIWN" NUMBER(10,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 104857600 NEXT 104857600 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AUTODATA01"
```

I was thinking about to select blocks of records (e.g. of 100.000), concatenate them internally and after it finishes to "export them". However this seems to take long too . Based on my estimation it would take about 20 hours.

```
  OS : Solaris 
  DB : Oracle 11g
```

Comment: If you need all the table, the fastest query is simply `select * from your_tab`, there's no going faster than that (`parallel` might or might not help - depends what your bottleneck is). What are you using to do the export?

Comment: Theoretically you can speedup the export simply by executing it at the "right" time. If there is a huge DML against this table the full table scan can be slower. First of all you have to find what is your bottleneck.

Comment: @Mat select * from your_tab is not the fastest query due the network issues. I'm using oracle sql developer

Comment: @Ivan I run it at the right time. I think the query itself is slow. Some 'parallel' stuff would help.

Comment: or perhaps dbms_output /  utl_file

Comment: why the down-vote ? you don't need to down-vote the question id you don't know the answer

Comment: If your issue is the network, then nothing on the query side will help. Certainly not any parallelism. Please clarify exactly what you can do on that database - can you export to a file on the server for instance?

Comment: If the issue is the network then bear in mind that sql*net has a fairly naive compression built in. http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/sqlnet-compression/ If there was a way of ordering (or clustering) the result without too much overhead then  it could be worth pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

Tom Kyte (of http://asktom.oracle.com fame) maintains [links](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteflat.html) to several different methods of "unloading" a table (or query) to CSV.

(expdp comment redacted.)

Comment: expdp has a command-line client that can run from a remote machine, but expdp requires a directory local to the host to which to export.

Comment: You can do an impdp over a network link though, @David.  (But indeed, expdp needs a directory on the server.)

Comment: I had forgotten that expdp writes server side (as it can run parallel).